# Creating game of war (cards)-- having trouble getting cards to print

Tags: python, class, object, methods

```
class PlayingCard:

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, rankNum, suitNum):
        self.rank = rankNum
        self.suit = suitNum

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.rank, self.suit)
    
    def getRank(self):
        if  self.rank == 11:
            return "Jacks"
        elif self.rank == 12:
            return "Queen"
        elif self.rank == 13:
            return  "King"
        elif self.rank == 14:
            return "Ace"
        else:    
            return self.rank
    
    def getSuit(self):
        if self.suit == 1:
            return "Clubs"
        elif self.suit == 2:
            return "Hearts"
        elif self.suit == 3:
            return "Diamonds"
        elif self.suit == 4:
            return "Spades"
                    
    def equals(self, otherCard):
        if self.rank == otherCard.rank and self.suit == otherCard.suit:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def trumps(self, otherCard):
        if self.rank > otherCard.rank:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This is the code I have so far. It runs, but the output ends up being "(name) drew the 9 of 1" when I want it to print it as "9 of Hearts" (aka the card descriptor). Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?? How do I get getRank to return the string descriptions into self.rank? Also, I didn't include the rest of the code for the war game because it works completely, it's just something with the way I'm returning the ranks and suits. However, if it's helpful for me to add it, I will!

Comment: You need to use `self.getSuit()` if you want to print the name of the suit

Comment: Try `return "{} of {}".format(self.getRank(), self.getSuit())` so that the return values of the function calls become the arguments of the "format" call.

Comment: Btw instead of `if condition: return True else: return False`. You can do just `return condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.rank, self.suit)
```

This is returning self.rank and self.suit.

So instead of `Jack of Hearts`, it would return `11 of 2`.

To return `Jack of Hearts`, you need to change your code to this:

```
def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.getRank(), self.getSuit())
```